# View returning 0 rows but same query returns 63 rows

Tags: mysql, view, amazon-rds

I am having strange results in mysql. I have a view which when executed returns 0 rows but taking the query out of the VIEW and executing it as it is returns 63 rows.

This was working properly but ever since I have migrated the code to AWS RDS I am having this error. I am not able to make any sense why this is happening?

I don't even get any error just the 0 rows being returned.

From here on I am just writing random words because I am not able to post the question as the line of code is more. THis is really annnoying ahh darn I made a typo it must be annoying and not annnoying. My bad I hope you all arent mad at this, I am at my wits end how much more should I type?

I am unable to create a sqlfiddle as the request is too large, I am creating a fiddle like dump if you guys want to recreate it on on your end.

I have also discovered that removing the left join from the VIEW returns results.

The fiddle like dump below returns 3 rows when running the select but the VIEW returns 0 rows

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_type` enum('admin','landlord','renter') NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `street_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone_no` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `bank_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `billing_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_on_card` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bank_account_number` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `bank_routing_no` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `has_payzang_account` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `payzang_api` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `payzang_gateway_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pending_amount` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'pending key bank(rent deduct) amount for landlord',
  `is_active` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '0-inactive/1-active',
  `is_assigned` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is this user assigned to any property',
  `assigned_to` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'assigned to which landlord id',
  `is_set_up_new_password` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'When admin/landlord adds renter or admin adds landlord an email with id+password is sent to the user. The first time they sign in, it should prompt them to change password page. So this field indicating whether user set up their own password',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `modified_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `user_type`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email_id`, `password`, `company_name`, `street_address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `phone_no`, `bank_name`, `billing_address`, `name_on_card`, `bank_account_number`, `bank_routing_no`, `has_payzang_account`, `payzang_api`, `payzang_gateway_url`, `pending_amount`, `is_active`, `is_assigned`, `assigned_to`, `is_set_up_new_password`, `created_at`, `modified_at`, `created_by`, `modified_by`, `is_deleted`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', 'Super', 'Admin', 'email@email.com', '$2y$10$NwcR0ObYeUM.OfjgMOaajeH6bjjuMTpU2GnF0h623SER37AFk8K9i', 'UIGJ', 'DJ Road', 'Kolkatr', '20', '522236', '(987) 963-9658', '', '', '', '', '', 1, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'https://payzang.transactiongateway.com/api/v2/three-step', '0.00', 1, 0, 0, '1', '2017-06-02 13:56:34', '2017-06-02 13:56:34', 0, 0, 0),
(2, 'landlord', 'Denise', 'Supplee', 'email1@email.com', '$2y$10$PATxnED1/lqr1t7epLJiwu0uVztuXJB97q/XQv7xLc/iCv/m4NK2G', '', '', '', '', '', '2156755615', '', '', '', '', '', 1, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'https://payzang.transactiongateway.com/api/v2/three-step', '230.77', 1, 0, 0, '0', '2017-09-06 16:31:23', '2017-09-10 05:48:45', 0, 1, 0),
(3, 'renter', 'Amanda', 'Scott', 'email2@email.com', '$2y$10$oBU3tbcVT63Asw6CDLCGB.SNAvSpJaOcLBx4NqodFNMwvlSRLc.tO', '', '', '', '', '', '(215) 672-3778', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', NULL, 0, 0, 2, '1', '2017-09-06 17:54:02', '2017-09-06 17:54:02', 2, 0, 1),
(4, 'renter', 'Megan', 'Ridgell', 'email3@email.com', '$2y$10$mPR7U/ri/rpW2n5f6X4mV.6jCycvLTJ/dvttR8seMFSGgRR/tQh1.', '', '', '', '', '', '2154852222', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', NULL, 0, 0, 11, '1', '2017-09-06 18:30:01', '2017-09-12 06:22:23', 0, 2, 1),
(5, 'landlord', 'Brian', 'Davis', 'email4@email.com', '$2y$10$NwcR0ObYeUM.OfjgMOaajeH6bjjuMTpU2GnF0h623SER37AFk8K9i', '', 'PO Box 123', 'Baltimore', '21', '21231', '4104999026', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', '0.00', 1, 0, 0, '0', '2017-09-07 05:19:46', '2017-09-07 05:19:46', 0, 0, 0),
(6, 'renter', 'Greg', 'Davis', 'email5@email.com', '$2y$10$Bd6S4KMGec2NzqKcvsJ1huwmbfACu8oOn56JLFSVQFt6ANg0Vr.ZW', '', '', '', '', '', '4104999026', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', NULL, 1, 0, 5, '1', '2017-09-07 05:30:58', '2017-09-17 04:22:30', 0, 2, 0),
(7, 'renter', 'Maddie', 'Evans', 'email6@email.com', '$2y$10$ry9DBBFJHRhCsV7wpU9s9OI9WQ8BWqCTdk0K9KyYw/VD10mb/yC3O', '', '', '', '', '', '4104999026', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', NULL, 1, 0, 0, '0', '2017-09-07 06:07:10', '2017-09-17 04:14:48', 0, 5, 0),
(8, 'renter', 'Arijita', 'Dey', 'email7@email.com', '$2y$10$NwcR0ObYeUM.OfjgMOaajeH6bjjuMTpU2GnF0h623SER37AFk8K9i', '', '', '', '', '', '3433453535', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', NULL, 0, 0, 2, '0', '2017-09-07 08:08:21', '2017-09-10 05:42:58', 0, 2, 1),
(9, 'renter', 'Arijita', 'Dey', 'email8@email.com', '$2y$10$NwcR0ObYeUM.OfjgMOaajeH6bjjuMTpU2GnF0h623SER37AFk8K9i', '', '', '', '', '', '(564) 564-5645', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', NULL, 0, 0, 5, '0', '2017-09-07 11:05:33', '2017-09-07 11:05:33', 5, 0, 1),
(10, 'renter', 'Rick', 'Roy', 'email9@email.com', '$2y$10$PG/8SkAwOZsSkD.px9FGveFIbriavOTX6vdBWHHmdjQeKgbwr0/wu', '', '', '', '', '', '(533) 453-4534', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', '', NULL, 0, 0, 5, '0', '2017-09-07 11:11:49', '2017-09-07 11:11:49', 5, 0, 1),
(11, 'landlord', 'Denise', 'Supplee', 'email0@email.com', '$2y$10$52H0QZMFK9ApK7JwaDV9qOlqyOxcyTH3QikQqXgAcLD.zrb.ggoQG', '', '', '', '', '', '2156755615', '', '', '', '', '', 1, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'https://payzang.transactiongateway.com/api/v2/three-step', '0.00', 1, 0, 0, '0', '2017-09-11 14:09:03', '2017-09-18 23:22:57', 0, 1, 0);

CREATE TABLE `lease_with_max_id` (
`id` int(11)
,`lease_id` int(11)
,`renter_id` int(11)
,`landlord_id` int(11)
,`property_id` int(11)
,`is_rent_deducted_form_filled_up` enum('0','1')
,`status` int(11)
,`is_deleted` enum('0','1')
,`is_lease_ended` enum('0','1')
);
CREATE TABLE `properties` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'landlord''s id',
  `property_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `street_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `street_address_2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `rent_amount` decimal(18,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `is_active` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
  `is_assigned` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is assigned to some renter or not',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `properties` (`id`, `user_id`, `property_name`, `street_address`, `street_address_2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `rent_amount`, `is_active`, `is_assigned`, `created_at`, `modified_at`, `is_deleted`) VALUES
(1, 2, 'Test Property', '330 Crooked Billet Rd', '', 'Hatboro', '39', '19040', '0.00', '0', '0', '2017-09-10 05:38:12', '2017-09-10 05:38:12', 0),
(2, 2, '', '515 Main St', 'Apt. 1809', 'Horsham', '39', '19044', '0.00', '1', '1', '2017-10-09 04:24:50', '2017-10-09 04:24:50', 1),
(3, 5, 'Test 1', '123 Brian\'s Test St.', 'Apt. 2', 'Baltimore', '21', '21231', '0.00', '1', '0', '2017-09-07 05:21:10', '2017-09-07 05:21:10', 1),
(4, 5, 'Test 1', '123 Brian\'s Test St.', 'Apt. 2', 'Baltimore', '21', '21231', '0.00', '1', '0', '2017-09-07 05:21:18', '2017-09-07 05:21:18', 1),
(5, 5, 'Test 1', '123 Brian\'s Test St.', 'Apt. 1503', 'Baltimore', '21', '21231', '0.00', '0', '0', '2017-09-11 13:49:11', '2017-09-11 13:49:11', 1),
(6, 5, 'Test 2', '123 Brian\'s Test St.', 'Apt. 1', 'Baltimore', '21', '21231', '0.00', '1', '1', '2017-10-03 04:31:18', '2017-10-03 04:31:18', 0);

CREATE TABLE `geo_states` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `abv` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `is_state` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_lower48` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` float(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` float(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `population` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` float(8,2) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE VIEW `test` AS  SELECT
    `users`.`id` AS `id`,
    `users`.`user_type` AS `user_type`,
    `users`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
    `users`.`last_name` AS `last_name`,
    CONCAT(
        `users`.`first_name`,
        ' ',
        `users`.`last_name`
    ) AS `landlord_name`,
    `users`.`email_id` AS `email_id`,
    `users`.`password` AS `password`,
    `users`.`company_name` AS `company_name`,
    `users`.`street_address` AS `street_address`,
    `users`.`city` AS `city`,
    `users`.`state` AS `state`,
    `users`.`zip` AS `zip`,
    `users`.`phone_no` AS `phone_no`,
    `users`.`bank_name` AS `bank_name`,
    `users`.`billing_address` AS `billing_address`,
    `users`.`name_on_card` AS `name_on_card`,
    `users`.`bank_account_number` AS `bank_account_number`,
    `users`.`bank_routing_no` AS `bank_routing_no`,
    `users`.`has_payzang_account` AS `has_payzang_account`,
    (
        CASE WHEN(`users`.`has_payzang_account` = 0) THEN 'No' WHEN(`users`.`has_payzang_account` = 1) THEN 'Yes'
    END
) AS `has_payzang_account_custom`,
`users`.`payzang_api` AS `payzang_api`,
`users`.`payzang_gateway_url` AS `payzang_gateway_url`,
`users`.`pending_amount` AS `pending_amount`,
`users`.`is_active` AS `is_active`,
(
    CASE WHEN(`users`.`is_active` = '0') THEN 'Inactive' WHEN(`users`.`is_active` = '1') THEN 'Active'
END
) AS `is_active_custom`,
`users`.`is_assigned` AS `is_assigned`,
`users`.`assigned_to` AS `assigned_to`,
`users`.`is_set_up_new_password` AS `is_set_up_new_password`,
`users`.`created_at` AS `created_at`,
`users`.`modified_at` AS `modified_at`,
`users`.`created_by` AS `created_by`,
`users`.`modified_by` AS `modified_by`,
`users`.`is_deleted` AS `is_deleted`,
`lease_with_max_id`.`id` AS `lease_with_max_id_id`,
`lease_with_max_id`.`lease_id` AS `lease_with_max_id_lease_id`,
`lease_with_max_id`.`renter_id` AS `lease_with_max_id_renter_id`,
`lease_with_max_id`.`landlord_id` AS `lease_with_max_id_landlord_id`,
`lease_with_max_id`.`property_id` AS `lease_with_max_id_property_id`,
`lease_with_max_id`.`is_rent_deducted_form_filled_up` AS `lease_with_max_id_is_rent_deducted_form_filled_up`,
`lease_with_max_id`.`status` AS `lease_with_max_id_status`,
`lease_with_max_id`.`is_deleted` AS `lease_with_max_id_is_deleted`,
`properties`.`id` AS `property_id`,
`properties`.`user_id` AS `property_user_id`,
`properties`.`property_name` AS `property_property_name`,
`properties`.`street_address` AS `property_street_address`,
`properties`.`street_address_2` AS `property_street_address_2`,
`properties`.`city` AS `property_city`,
`properties`.`state` AS `property_state`,
`properties`.`zip` AS `property_zip`,
`properties`.`rent_amount` AS `property_rent_amount`,
`properties`.`is_active` AS `property_is_active`,
`properties`.`is_assigned` AS `property_is_assigned`,
`properties`.`created_at` AS `property_created_at`,
`properties`.`modified_at` AS `property_modified_at`,
`properties`.`is_deleted` AS `property_is_deleted`,
`geo_states`.`name` AS `geo_states_name`
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                `users`
            LEFT JOIN `lease_with_max_id` ON
                (
                    (
                        `lease_with_max_id`.`renter_id` = `users`.`id`
                    )
                )
            )
        LEFT JOIN `properties` ON
            (
                (
                    `properties`.`id` = `lease_with_max_id`.`property_id`
                )
            )
        )
    LEFT JOIN `geo_states` ON
        (
            (
                `geo_states`.`id` = `properties`.`state`
            )
        )
    )
WHERE
    (
        (`users`.`user_type` = 'landlord') AND(`users`.`is_deleted` = 0)
    )
ORDER BY
    `users`.`id`
DESC
    ;
```

Comment: That's a complex query. You might get better answers if you can reduce it to a simpler case. Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query and [edit] your question.

Comment: What you also can try is dropping the view and recreating it..

Comment: @O.Jones I have added the schema